# Scraping 'N' pages with Beautifulsoup and Requests (How to obtain the true page number)

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrape

I want to get all the titles() in the website.

```
http://www.shyan.gov.cn/zwhd/web/webindex.action
```

Now, my code successfully scrapes only one page. However, there are multiple pages available at the site above in which I would like to to scrape.

For example, with the url above, when I click the link to "page 2", the overall url does NOT change. I looked at the page source and saw javascript code to advance to the next page like this: javascript:gotopage(2) or  javascript:void(0).
My code is here (get page 1)

```
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
import requests
url = 'http://www.shyan.gov.cn/zwhd/web/webindex.action'
r =  requests.get(url)
soup = Beautifulsoup(r.content,'lxml')
titles = soup.select('td.tit3 > a')
for title in titles:
    print(title.get_text())
```

How can my code be changed to scrape titles from all the available listed pages?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much!But I cannot get the next page either.My code is below.Please help me to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following URL format:

http://www.shiyan.gov.cn/zwhd/web/webindex.action?keyWord=&searchType=3&page.currentpage=2&page.pagesize=15&page.pagecount=2357&docStatus=&sendOrg=

The site is using javascript to pass hidden page information to the server to request the next page. When you view the source you will find:

```
<form action="/zwhd/web/webindex.action" id="searchForm" name="searchForm" method="post">
 <div class="item">
     <div class="titlel">
      <span>留言查询</span>
     <label class="dow"></label>
     </div>
     <input type="text" name="keyWord" id="keyword" value="" class="text"/>
     <div class="key">
        <ul>
            <li><span><input type="radio" checked="checked" value="3" name="searchType"/></span><p>编号</p></li>
            <li><span><input type="radio" value="2" name="searchType"/></span><p>关键字</p></li>
        </ul>    
     </div>
     <input type="button" class="btn1" onclick="search();" value="查询"/>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="pageIndex" name="page.currentpage" value="2"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="pageSize" name="page.pagesize" value="15"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="pageCount" name="page.pagecount" value="2357"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="docStatus" name="docStatus" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" id="sendorg" name="sendOrg" value=""/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks,this is a good  choice. It is easier to understand than selenium.

Comment: @vassilo How did you come up with that URL (in terms of formatting the hidden elements into the url)?

Comment: I use Google Chrome's DevTools to inspect the web page's requests when I click a next page link. Identify the appropriate request and you're good to go.

Comment: @vassilo, I'd like to up-rep your answer. It will only let me do so if it is edited (if you can make a very small edit, I should be able to do so).