# Is it possible to use browser parameters and BeautifulSoup instead of Selenium for dynamically loaded elements on this website?

Tags: ajax, selenium, beautifulsoup

**Update**: issue has been solved and answer should be posted shortly

My goal is to use BeautifulSoup here, if possible, to avoid using Selenium (and timeouts) which has had some issues with refreshing elements when simulating clicking through pagination.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684949/scraping-n-pages-with-beautifulsoup-and-requests-how-to-obtain-the-true-page) has an accepted answer that apparently does what I’m looking for. In that answer, there are shown to be hidden browser request parameters in the html that can be formatted to a URL to load a page as if it were static html.

I attempt to do that on [this](http://www.rci.com/resort-directory/list-view?resortFilter=ALL&regionName=&searchKey=Ne%3D4294942695%2B4294945349%2B4294966866%2B34%2B%26N%3D2876459038%2B4294942550&sortKey=P_ResortName%3A1&recCount=10#?searchKey=Ne%3D4294942695%2B4294945349%2B4294966866%2B34%2B%26N%3D2876459038&sortKey=P_ResortName%3A1&recCount=10&isRemoving=true&resortFilter=ALL) site, but the elements aren’t being refreshed for each page when trying to access each subsequent pagination link.

In the html, there is a browser request parameter stored in the pagination link elements (the value for “Nao”), which can manually be passed as the second “searchKey” parameter (`searchKey=Nao=…`) in the browser URL. This works to access each pagination link when done manually (just by incrementing the value `Nao` value by 10 for each link), but doesn't refresh elements with `requests` or `mechanize` modules. The same elements are retrieved each time despite updating the `Nao` pagination value.

Is it impossible to load elements with BeautifulSoup on a page that is using AJAX? I found an additional ajax=false argument that could be passed from the browser, but this appeared to have no effect.

Comment: Did you try solutions from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025082/headless-browser-for-python-javascript-support-required) yet?

Comment: What are you trying to parse?

Comment: I'm trying to parse resorts listings (10 per page in the example given) for each page link (only the first link had unique results). However, I received a private message that solved the problem. I am waiting for the answer to be posted here.

Comment: Where do you get private messages on SO?

Comment: ...not on SO. Someone had previously given an email requesting an exchange of information.